# Method of binding socket.io sessions

Tags: node.js, tomcat, websocket, socket.io, session-cookies

I have an existing Tomcat application which has an existing authentication and session management and I am currently building a NodeJS server to handle real time communication with users via web sockets (using Socket.IO).

My question is what is the best method of keeping a session for the websockets given that the user will never visit the NodeJs server and no cookies are set upon connecting via the web socket and there is currently no persistence when the socket is closed (i.e when a user moves between pages).

I have seen methods of doing this when using Express and Socket on the same site but never when using Socket.io only for web sockets. Is this possible?

Comment: If there is no cookies - then there is no chance you can securely restore session.
You can make authentication straight after connecting, and then keep cookies. After refreshing page - it will reconnect and use cookies to restore session.